# Custom Helper can't render content of PartialView

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The html.Partial doesn't working very well, in fact it shows just path `~/Views/Shared/IconMenuPSA.cshtml`, instead of showing the HTML content.

Where am I doing wrong?

My simple custom Helper in App_Code folder:

**Helper**

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html

@helper DefaultTitle(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, string content) {
    <br />
    <div class="well well-sm text-center text-primary">
        html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/IconMenuPSA.cshtml")
        <p style="font-size:x-large">@content</p>
    </div>
}
```

**View**

```
@model DatiGeneraliViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "DatiGenerali";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutMainPage.cshtml";
}
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

@MyHelper.DefaultTitle(Html, "Dati Generali")
```

**PartialView**

```
<div style="float:left">
    <!-- Split button -->
    <div class="btn-group">

        <a href="MainPage" class="btn btn-primary" title="Torna al cruscotto">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks"></span>
        </a>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="caret"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
        </button>

        <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
            <li><a href="MainPage">Cruscotto</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="DatiGenerali">Dati Generali</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="SezioneRiepilogo">Riepilogo </a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>

</div>
```

How do I fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure if it will fix the problem but are you not setting the model for the partial view. Also Im not sure if its case sensetive, but usually you want to do `@Html.Partial(view, model)` instead of `html.Partial(view)`

Comment: Hi. Thanks. The PartialView doesn't use any Model. HTML.PartialView in Helper is not accessible, infact I had to passing Html context frm View.

Comment: Can you try `html.RenderPartial("~/link/to/View.cshtml")`?

Comment: No, Same result! ;(

Comment: @Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/IconMenuPSA.cshtml") Try this

Comment: Error Compiler 
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'RenderPartial'... as I Said before to @nbokmans. Thanks